# Как правильно работать с подзапросами в SQL?

Tags: sql

Здраствуйте. Помогите пожалуйста с подзапросами в SQL. Таск:

> Напишите запрос, выбирающий данные об именах всех студентов, имеющих
> по предмету с идентификатором 10 балл выше общего среднего балла.

Я пытался сделать, но похоже не получилось. Мой код:

```
SELECT * 
FROM STUDENT, EXAM_MARKS, SUBJECT
WHERE EXAM_MARKS.SUBJ_ID = 10 AND 
    MAR > 
    (SELECT AVG(MAR)
     FROM EXAM_MARKS)
```

Ответ выводят в 80 строк.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица STUDENT:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица EXAM_MARKS:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица SUBJECT:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите мою ошибку, please)

Comment: Вы не связали таблицы во FROM основного запроса.

Comment: Связали?? Не понимаю вас.)

Comment: Сейчас у Вас КАЖДАЯ запись из, скажем, STUDENT, прикладывается к КАЖДОЙ записи из EXAM_MARKS - и пофиг, этого студента оценка или другого. Вы должны добавить условия, которые оставят только соответствующие друг другу записи из таблиц. Почитайте справку по JOIN для вашей СУБД.